# Get ISO year week in Apache Spark using scala / from_unixtime behaving differently in Spark and Hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, week-number

I am trying to get ISO year week in Spark with scala from a date which is in string format.

The following SQL query returns the expected result in hive.
i.e if the date is 1st January 2016, as per ISO standard it is 53rd week of year 2015 and hence the result **201553**.

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20160101', 'yyyyMMdd'), 'Yww');
OK
201553
Time taken: 0.444 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

If I try to run the same in Spark via Spark sql, it is giving me a different result.

```
scala> spark.sql("""select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20160101', 'yyyyMMdd'), 'Yww')""").show
+------------------------------------------------------+
|from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(20160101, yyyyMMdd), Yww)|
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                201601|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The result I need from Spark program in **201553**.
I am using Spark version 2.3
Can someone explain what's going on?
Please let me know if there is any way to get ISO year week in Spark.

Comment: Well, weekofyear gives the correct result, but as you said, I also got the same result for that.

Comment: what version of spark are you using?

Comment: @Oli I am using Spark version 2.3

Comment: @Lamanus Yes weekofyear gives the correct ISO week, but I need ISO year as well . The year function would return 2016 but I want the ISO year which is 2015